# Google autocomplete Swift UITextField

Tags: ios, swift, google-places-api

Has anyone came across any resources on how to add GoogleAutoComplete on a UITextField. I have only seen tutorials on how to add a search bar to a navigation controller or outdated and full of errors. I want to add it to a UITextField. Haven't found any working solutions for Swift 4 on GitHub.

Answer (score 0):

`import GooglePlaces` into your file then pass `UITextField` text into this method:-

```
let placeClient = GMSPlacesClient.init()
let filter = GMSAutocompleteFilter()
filter.type = .establishment
filter.country = "in" //in for India (Only India address will be searched)
placeClient.autocompleteQuery("Pass your text here", bounds: nil, filter: filter) { (results, error) in
    if let err = error {
        print("Autocomplete error \(err)")
        return
    }
    if let results = results {
        // show result in your table view
    }
}
```

Comment: I am getting Expected declaration error on filter.type = .establishment